# Как получить DOM через СОМ объект

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, dom, com

Я хочу программно нажимать на кнопки сайта. Для этого решил использовать СОМ объект InternetExplorer. Выгрузить его в DOM  и там уже кликать по кнопкам. Делаю это так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#import "progid:InternetExplorer.Application"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
bool showIE = true;
SHDocVw::IWebBrowserAppPtr  ptrIE(_T("InternetExplorer.Application"));

ptrIE->Visible = (showIE ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE);

ptrIE->Navigate("https://vk.com");
int i = 0;
// ждем пока загрузится страница по url
while (ptrIE->Busy)
    i++;

// получаем html-страницу как DOM (объектная модель документа)
//auto pdisp = ptrIE->Document;
IDispatch pdisp = (ptrIE->Document).GetInterfacePtr();
HRESULT hresult;
DISPID dispid;
OLECHAR *szMember = L"querySelector";
hresult = pdisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &szMember, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);

return 0;
}
```

Но при выполнении функции GetIDsOfNames программа вылетает с ошибкой access violation reading location. Правильно ли я понимаю, что у меня в pdisp указатель в никуда?

UPDATE

Не надо было вызвывать GetInterfacePtr(), так как он возвращает указатель в никуда.
немного переделал код теперь он выглядит вот так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Mshtml.h"
#include "comutil.h"
#import "progid:InternetExplorer.Application"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
bool showIE = true;
SHDocVw::IWebBrowser2Ptr ptrIE(_T("InternetExplorer.Application"));

ptrIE->Visible = (showIE ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE);

HRESULT hr = ptrIE->Navigate("myUrl");
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
}
int i = 0;
// ждем пока загрузится страница по url
while (ptrIE->Busy)
    i++;

// получаем html-страницу как DOM (объектная модель документа)
IHTMLDocument3 *doc3;
hr = ptrIE->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument3, (void**)&doc3);
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

IHTMLElement *parentElem;
hr = doc3->getElementById(_com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR("intro-step-4"), &parentElem);
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

IDispatch * pDisp;
hr = parentElem->get_children(&pDisp);
parentElem->Release();
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

IHTMLElementCollection *elemCol;
hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElementCollection, (void **)&elemCol);  
pDisp->Release();
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

_variant_t index = 0;
hr = elemCol->item(index, index, &pDisp);
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

IHTMLElement * childElem;
hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void **)&childElem);
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

BSTR *pszText = new BSTR;
hr = childElem->click();
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);
hr = childElem->get_innerText(pszText);
if FAILED(hr) return(hr);

    return 0;
}
```

Судя по тексту который я получаю в hr = childElem->get_innerText(pszText) я нашел нужный мне элемент. Но метод click() хотя и возвращает S_OK, но клик не производит. По крайней мере никакой реакции в открытом браузере нет. Что делать?

Comment: Возможно. А проверить в коде? :)

Comment: указатель не равен 0. Там есть конкретный адрес. А как узнать указывает ли он на кусок памяти который уже освободили?

Comment: На интерес, посмотри тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879041/how-to-interact-with-internet-explorer-c там как-то по-другому получают указатель на документ, возможно, надо держать на него хэндл, чтобы `GetInterfacePtr()` не инвалидировался.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте умные COM-указатели

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IHTMLDocument2, __uuidof(IHTMLDocument2));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IHTMLDocument3, __uuidof(IHTMLDocument3));
IDispatchPtr d = ptrIE->Document;
IHTMLDocument2Ptr doc2;
IHTMLDocument3Ptr doc3;
d->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&doc2);
doc2->...
d->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument3, (void**)&doc3);
```

Я попробовал получить указатель на интерфейс `IHtmlSelector` (чтобы использовать метод `querySelector`, но у меня не вышло).

У себя я делаю так:

```
 if ( SUCCEEDED(doc3->getElementsByTagName(L"HTML", &collection)) ){
            long count = 0;
            if (SUCCEEDED(collection->get_length(&count)) && count ) {
                IDispatch*  disp = 0;
                VARIANT v;
                ::VariantInit(&v);
                v.vt = VT_I4;
                v.iVal = 0;
                IElementSelectorPtr selector;
                collection->item(v, v, &disp);
                disp->QueryInterface(IID_IElementSelector, (void**)&selector);
                selector->querySelector(...);
            }
        }
```

Но здесь это не работает. 
Правда `IWebBrowserApp` считается устаревшим. Используйте `IWebBrowser2`.